# SpringBoot retry, remaining retries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have used spring declarative retry in my project like

```
@Service
class Service {
  @Async  @Retryable(maxAttempts=12, backoff=@Backoff(delay=100, maxDelay=500))
    public service() {
        // ... do something
    }
}
```

Now, I have two questions.

1. Is it fine to use retry with async, I don't have any issue, just
   want to be sure.
2. The second requirement is, if the process fails I want to log it to log file including the number of remaining retries. So, is there a way to pass, or obtain the number of remaining retries from inside the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `@Recover` annotation to perform an action on each fail and keep a count inside your object outside of the methods. Make sure no other methods interact with this counter. Here is the basic premise:

```
@Service
class Service {


private int attemptsLeft=12;

@Retryable(maxAttempts=12, backoff=@Backoff(delay=100, maxDelay=500))
public service() {
    // ... do something that throws a KnownException you create to catch later on.
}

@Recover
public void connectionException(KnownException e) {
            this.attemptsLeft = this.attemptsLeft-1; //decrease your failure counter
            Logger.warn("Retry attempts left:{}",attemptsLeft);
        }
}
```

If you don't want a member variable tracking count, you might need to ditch the annotations and declare the `RetryTemplate` to get access to the context, with the `getRetryCount()` method.

```
public String serviceWithRetry() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    final SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(12);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInterval(100L);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Void, RuntimeException>() 
        return retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Void, RuntimeException>() {
        @Override
        public void doWithRetry(RetryContext context) {
            LOG.info("Retry of connection count: {}", context.getRetryCount());
            return //something with your connection logic
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the directions. That came to my mind, but a Service is a pretty much concurrent object where no state should be kept. As you have seen in my post, I also use @Async annotation, therefore private int attemptsLeft=12; this can't be a work around. I may use an Atomic integer, but then I also need a way to distinguish the vars by thread. Other option would be thread local, but I wonder why there is not a simpler work around. Or is there?

Comment: Thanks, seems like there is no way around with annotation.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way around using the annotations, @Recover annotated method executes only after the last failed retry, not after each one failing.

[Refer to this github documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry)

An excerpt from the link above- "Call the "service" method and if it fails with a RemoteAccessException then it will retry (up to three times by default), and then execute the "recover" method if unsuccessful."

Even with using RetryTemplate the Retry callback is called only after all retries are exhausted.

Another excerpt form the same link- "When a retry is exhausted the RetryOperations can pass control to a different callback, the RecoveryCallback. To use this feature clients just pass in the callbacks together to the same method"

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, but the recover method was good enough from my requirement. I can live without the count as long as recover is there.